# ASCII Desired Range loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ascii, offset

I have built a QR Code scanner on raspberry pi. i wish to have the data offset by a desired ascii value set by the user so that the data is somewhat hidden. The only ascii value i wish to represent are the printable characters 32-126. 
My Issue - say for example I wish to type hello with an offset of 1. this would be represented as 'ifmmp'. this works no bother but if i wish to represent values which are closer to ascii value 126 i get issues as i get the extended ascii charcters - not my intention.

hope you can help

Thanks in advance

```
         # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it
     # on our output image we need to convert it to a string first
     barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("ascii")


     #Change the decoded ascii string by a value of desired charcters
     barcodeData = "".join(chr(ord(c) - 5) for c in barcodeData)
```

Comment: A common arrangement is to wrap around so that 126+1=32, etc; but it's up to you really how to define this.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your reply, how would i impliment that?

Comment: Hints: subtraction, modulo, addition; google Ceasar cipher.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically trying to implement is a version of the Caesar cipher, but operating over the entire printable ASCII range instead of the alphabet characters.

```
def encode_string(s, offset):
    return ''.join(chr(32+((ord(ch)-32)+offset)%95) for ch in s)

# Examples:

encode_string('~~ Hello, World! ~~', 1)
'  !Ifmmp-!Xpsme"!  '
encode_string('  !Ifmmp-!Xpsme"!  ', -1)
'~~ Hello, World! ~~'
```

The `%` symbol is called the modulus operator. It calculates the remainder of one number when divided by another. By subtracting 32 from the initial ASCII value, you get a number in the range 0–94. You can then add or subtract whatever you like from this, and then you can use this modulus operator to constrain the result to another number in the range 0–94. Add 32 to the result, and you get your encoded result back.